Stream of null elements returns true
I have a simple validator method. Why the stream of null elements returns true? How does it works?
What happens after filtering on null?
private static boolean isNotValidCeo(List<Ceo> ceos) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(ceos)) {
        return true;
    }

    return ceos.stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .map(Ceo::getSuperBonus)
            .allMatch(Objects::isNull);
}



check documentation of allMatch(): "Returns:
true if either ... or the stream is empty"

See also Vacuous Truth

You filter removes nulls but without code of getSuperBonus there isn't any clue as to whether the stream contains nulls or not afterwards.

allMatch(isNull) is equivalent to noneMatch(nonNull) or !anyMatch(nonNull), which means it will pass unless there's a non-null element.

.filter(Objects::nonNull) results in empty set and allMatch on an empty set is true, because there are no elements to contradict the rule.

The stream is empty when allMatch is called (since all values have been filtered out by .filter(Objects::nonNull)).  allMatch on an empty stream always returns true.
This behavior of allMatch is documented in the method's JavaDocs:

API Note:
This method evaluates the universal quantification of the predicate over the elements of the stream (for all x P(x)). If the stream is empty, the quantification is said to be vacuously satisfied and is always true (regardless of P(x)).
[…]
Returns:
true if either all elements of the stream match the provided predicate or the stream is empty, otherwise false

